# Can I use predictor variable in percentages in multiple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression

The situation is as follows:
Outcome variable is numeric, and values are indicating salary of a subject.
And I have 3 independent variables:

1. Age (in years)
2. Experience (in years)
3. Skill in percentages (1-100)

This is factious example from my stats class btw. 
Tthe question is, can I use 3rd independent variable in my regression model to predict outcome?

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. It seems that skill is a continuous variable, so it's adequate to predict the outcome. (I'm assuming that other [assumptions are also met](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions))

Comment: Of what quantity is skill a "percentage"?  It seems to me it's just some number in the arbitrary range 1-100.  Given that, why wouldn't it work just as well as any other variable that might be related to salary?

Answer (score 2):

If I may, I believe that the question you are asking is less about *if* a percentage can be used as a predictor, but rather *should* it be used.  Any input *can* be used as a predictor.  Whether or not this improves the model is another question.

The answer to this first question is that the units do not matter.

Let's take an example.

In a simple linear regression model you have an outcome $Y$ and an input $X$.  The goal is to find $\beta$ so that

$Y = X\beta$

is a good fit.

Assume that the percentage of skill was based on a measurable skill value, such as SAT score.

$$\text{Skill Percent} = \frac{\text{SAT Score of Individual}}{\text{Total SAT scores of all people}}$$

Then the model input is just a scalar multiple of the raw SAT score.  This is just divided by the total score, which is just some number.

$$\text{Let } \alpha = \frac{1}{\text{Total SAT scores of all people}}$$

Then the model which you are fitting is

$Y = X(\beta \alpha) = X\beta^*$ where $\beta^*$ is still a real number.

Comment: The Skill variable is measured as appraisal of person's beauty by more than one person. In this example, the goal is too consider person's attractiveness as important variable in predicting outcome.
I've named is Skill not knowing it would make a difference, but now when I see your reply, I see that it is important. With this new information, does it change anything in your reply?

Comment: @ZmajOdNocaja as this answer nicely says: "Any input can be used as a predictor. Whether or not this improves the model is another question." That's true however you came up with your "percentage" score. As [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261403/28500) put it for a similar question about integers as predictors: "There's no more need to do anything to integers than there is to do anything to some continuous predictor -- at least not on the basis that they're integers ... the critical thing is your understanding ... of how the predictor variable might relate to the response."